# Java store boolean array in file and read fast

Tags: java, arrays, io, boolean

I need to store boolean array with 80,000 items in file. I don't care how much time saving takes, I'm interested only in the loading time of array.
I did't try to store it by DataOutputStream because it requires access for each value.

I tried to make this by 3 approaches, such as:

1. serialize boolean array
2. use BitSet instead of boolean array an serialize it
3. transfer boolean array into byte array, where 1 is true and 0 is false appropriately and write it by FileChannel using ByteBuffer

To test reading from files by these approaches, I had run each approach 1,000 times in loop. So I got results which look like this:

1. deserialization of boolean array takes 574 ms
2. deserialization of BitSet - 379 ms
3. getting byte array from FileChannel by MappedByteBuffer - 170 ms

The first and second approaches are too long, the third, perhaps, is not approach at all.

Perhaps there are a best way to accomplish it, so I need your advice

**EDIT**

Each method ran once

1. 13.8
2. 8.71
3. 6.46
   ms appropriatively

Comment: How are you measuring the results of the execution of this data?

Comment: Loading the same file 1000 times in a loop won't give you a true sense of how long each iteration takes - the first will be far slower, and after that the file system cache will kick in.

Comment: @Luiggi I had run each of them 1 thousand time in loop and take time by System.currentTimeMills() or System.nanoTime()

Comment: @Jon ok, give me a minute to test it single time

Comment: 1. 13.8
2.   8.71
3.   6.46
ms appropriatively

Comment: Why can't you access each value of the array on it's own?

Comment: @davidgiga1993 because it's too long

Comment: @davidgiga1993 I mean execute 80K times get() method instead of getting array in one time is very long

Comment: When you can get the whole array you can still access it by index so writing a custom algorithm just for storing booleans should be no problem.

Comment: @davidgiga1993 thing that you had said is obviously, I need approach to read 80K booleans faster than 13.8 ms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about writing a byte for each boolean and develop a custom parser? This will propably one of the fastest methods.
If you want to save space you could also put 8 booleans into one byte but this would require some bit shifting operations.

Here is a short example code:

```
public void save() throws IOException
{
    boolean[] testData = new boolean[80000];
    for(int X=0;X < testData.length; X++)
    {
        testData[X] = Math.random() > 0.5;
    }
    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.bin"));

    for (boolean item : testData)
    {
        stream.write(item ? 1 : 0);
    }
    stream.close();
}

public boolean[] load() throws IOException
{
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    File file = new File("test.bin");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    int fileLength = (int) file.length();

    byte[] data = new byte[fileLength];
    boolean[] output = new boolean[fileLength];

    inputStream.read(data);
    for (int X = 0; X < data.length; X++)
    {
        if (data[X] != 0)
        {
            output[X] = true;
            continue;
        }
        output[X] = false;
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime() - start;
    Console.log("Time: " + end);
    return output;
}
```

It takes about 2ms to load 80.000 booleans.
Tested with JDK 1.8.0_45

Comment: it takes from 4 to 6 ms on my machine, interesting, but I'm using JDK 1.7.0_79

Comment: the reading of byte array takes 0.71 ms, this is amazing
I can't just understand why nio reads 80.000 bytes 6 ms, when FileInputStream only half of ms?

Answer (score 0):

So I had a very similar use case where i wanted to serialise/deserialise a very large boolean array.

I implemented something like this,
Firstly i converted boolean array to an integer array simply to club multiple boolean values (This makes storage more efficient and there are no issues with bit padding)

This now means we have to build wrapper methods which will give true/false

```
    private boolean get (int index) {
        int holderIndex = (int) Math.floor(index/buckets);
        int internalIndex = index % buckets;
        return 0 != (container[holderIndex] & (1 << internalIndex));
    }
```

and

```
    private void set (int index) {
        int holderIndex = (int) Math.floor(index/buckets);
        int internalIndex = index % buckets;
        int value = container[holderIndex];
        int newValue = value | (1 << internalIndex);
        container[holderIndex] = newValue;
    }
```

Now to serialise and deserialise you can directly convert this to bytestream and write to file.

my source code, for [reference](https://github.com/swayamraina/flash-card/blob/master/server/src/main/java/dev/swayamraina/flashcard/storage/worker/BloomFilter.java)